# getting the facebook profile picture with a simple NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the URL for facebook profile pictures in objective-c. I am doing it as follow.

```
-(NSString *)getProfileURL:(NSString *)userId{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    NSString *requestURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture",userId];
    NSLog(@"request url is %@",requestURL);
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestURL]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:60.0];

    NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"data received from url: %@", data);

    return data;
}
```

When I copy and past the log from requestURL in my browser, I got the right image. But when I look at the log `"Data received from url: "`. I always getting   `(null)`.

Any help?

Comment: You can use this URL to fetch pictures

http://graph.facebook.com/idUser/picture?type=normal ... also you can do graph api..take a look to facebook docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/graphapi/

Comment: Yes but with my url I also get the picture. But it is not storing it in the Data component.

Comment: maybe your request is returning null

Comment: you should start using AFNetworking, its better to see and control your requests, so its easier to see what response you are getting... https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: In other apps I work with AFNetworking, but I don't want to implement the AFNetworking project only for getting these images.

Comment: debug mode and see whats the content of urlData

Comment: comment the line where you set the Content-Type header, the value `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` should only be used to send files in a POST(PUT) method

Comment: @tkanzakic so just comment that line out?

Comment: yes, this could be the problem

Comment: mm, no succes, still gettin null. Any other idea maybe ?

Comment: No, here I'm getting something like this <ffd8ffe0 00104a46 49460001....

Comment: ok, I has similar problem in an old project, the solution for me was modify the way the `NSData` object is *converted* to a `NSString`, I use the function: `NSString *data = [NSString stringWithCString:[data bytes] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24712/discussion-between-stef-geelen-and-tkanzakic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

accordingly to the [Graph API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/), the URL that you are calling returns the image directly, thats why you can load the returned value into a `NSString`, you can instead create an `UIImage` instance, like this:

```
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error]; 
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:urlData];
```